# scrapyd-deploy with "deploy failed (400)"

Tags: scrapy, scrapyd, scrapyd-deploy

I am trying to deploy with scrapyd-deploy to a remote scrapyd server, which failes without error message:

```
% scrapyd-deploy                                                       
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/scrapyd-deploy:23: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Module `scrapy.utils.http` is deprecated, Please import from `w3lib.http` instead.
  from scrapy.utils.http import basic_auth_header
fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.
Packing version r3-master
Deploying to project "crawler" in http://ip:6843/addversion.json
Deploy failed (400):
```

No further error message has been displayed. Can somebody help to resolve this?

Comment: Which version of Python and twisted are you using? In [this case](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd/issues/309) with python-3.7 it seems like the issue got solved by upgrading twisted to 18.9 or later.

Comment: Good hint! That would explain why it is working on my local system. 17.9.0 is installed on my ubuntu 18.04 system. Now I just need to figure out how to update :-)

Comment: `pip install -U Twisted==18.9.0`. Let me know if it solved your issue so I will convert the comment to an answer.

Comment: Boom!! Updated to twisted 20.3 and this solved it (run into other error, but this one solved) Thank you!!! I spent hours looking for a solution on google and everywhere without success!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moved from comment to answer:
In a [similar sounding issue](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd/issues/309) with the same error-code the problem was that `Twisted` versions earlier than 18.9 don't support python-3.7. If you are using python-3.7 and your twisted version is below 18.9, try upgrading twisted to at least version 18.9:

```
pip install -U Twisted==18.9.0
```

Comment: Thank you. Please consider upvoting this question as the solution is hard to find on SO, although you managed to spot on github, others might find it helpful on SO.